# How to find a sequence of pairwise disjoint measurable sets with pairwise different measures?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $m$ be a positive measure on a set $X$ such that the set of values of $m$ is infinite.
Is it true that there exis a sequence of pairwise disjoint measurable sets with pairwise different measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This will certainly work if we can write $X$ as an infinite disjoint union of sets $A_n$ with $m_n:=m(A_n)\in (0,\infty)$ (discuss separately the cases $\inf m_n=0$ and $m_n\ge\delta>0$ for infinitely many $n$).

Recall that an *atom* is defined as a measurable set $A$ with $m(A)>0$ such that if $B\subseteq A$ is also measurable, then $m(B)=0$ or $=m(A)$.

Now take an atom $A_1$ with $m(A_1)<\infty$, if we can find one, then search for finite atoms in $X\setminus A_1$ etc. If this produces an infinite sequence $A_n$, $n\ge 1$, then we're in the case discussed above. If the process stops after step $N\ge 0$, then set $A=\bigcup_{n\le N} A_n$ and consider $m':=\chi_{X\setminus A} m$. This new measure doesn't have finite atoms, and it still  has to deliver infinitely many values because we are getting at most $2^N+1$ values from the part we split off.

We can now take any set of positive finite $m'$ measure, split this into two parts of positive measure each and continue in this style to again obtain an infinite sequence of disjoint positive measure sets.